# posting multipart form from php online ( everything ok on localhost )

Tags: php, post

this i my code that on localhost outputs the correct text version of the pdf but when i put it on the online it doesnt send the file correctly os something like that and doesnt ouptu the convertet text . please need some help

```
<?php


//Target url
$url = "http://service.coolutils.com/PDF-Converter.php";


//Boundary definition
$boundary = "---------------------".substr(md5(rand(0,32000)), 0, 10);

//Post data
$data = "";

//Fields
$data .= "--$boundary\n";
$data .= "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"ConvertTo\"\n\ntxt\n";
$data .= "--$boundary\n";
$data .= "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Converter\"\n\npc\n";
$data .= "--$boundary\n";

//Files
$fileContents = file_get_contents('test.pdf');
$data .= "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filename\"; filename=\"test.pdf\"\n";
$data .= "Content-Type: application/pdf\n";
$data .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n\n";
$data .= $fileContents."\n";
$data .= "--$boundary\n";

//Header
//$optional_headers = header('Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary='.$boundary);



//Construct params
$params = array('http' => array(
 'method' => 'POST',
 'header' => 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary='.$boundary,
 'content' => $data
));

//Create context
$ctx = stream_context_create($params);

//Post data to url
$fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
if (!$fp) {
 echo "Error posting to $url: " . $php_errormsg;
 exit(1);
}

//Read response
$response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
if ($response === false) {
 throw new Exception("Problem reading data from $url, $php_errormsg");
 exit(1);
}

//Display response (with a little bit of formatting)
$response = strip_tags($response);
$response = preg_replace('/\s+\n/', "\n", $response);
$response = preg_replace('/\n\s+/', "\n", $response);
$response = preg_replace("'[ ]+'", ' ', $response);
echo $response;

echo "Done";
?>
```

UPDATE 14/04 - i simplified the code to make it more clear . Im using WAMP (win32) on localhost and it work vary well. the problem is that it doesnt work on linux server online.

the file "test.pdf" is located in the same folder of the script so anyone who will say that the problem is there just dont say it :D

Comment: Have you tried removing the error suppression (`@`) from `file_get_contents()` to see if it gives an error?

Comment: Have you checked whether your max post size and max file upload size are larger than the file you are trying to upload?

Comment: I would also consider wrapping the PHP portion of your script in a check to see if form was submitted so it isn't trying to execute the file processing code every time the page is loaded.

Comment: i tried removing the (@) and no error . the filesize is ok i checked it twice . everything seems to be ok because on localhost it is perfect o.O

Comment: @justin - i had done what youre saying and i made the filename "filename=test.pdf" that was on the same dir of the script and replacet this portion $data .= (file_get_contents($emri)) . $eol; with $data .=  (file_get_contents('test.pdf')) . $eol;

Answer (score 2):

I think you should check some things:

1. You call an external site over `file_get_contents`. So its possible that your firewall block the request.
2. I have checked your scripts and removed some mistakes. Print out the response then you get some information why its not working.

I my case i got "Your file is in Doc format. Please, use Total Doc Converter to convert it to other formats."

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

$tmp = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']; 
$emri = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
$madhesia= $_FILES['filename']['size'];
$file_src = dirname(__FILE__)."/uploads/";

if (move_uploaded_file($tmp, $file_src.$emri)) {
    echo 'Skedari u ngarkua me sukses.';
} else {
    echo 'Ndodhi nje problem ne ngarkim!';
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $destination = "http://service.coolutils.com/PDF-Converter.php";

    $eol = "\r\n";
    $data = '';

    $mime_boundary=md5(time());

    $data .= '--' . $mime_boundary . $eol;
    $data .= 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ConvertTo"' . $eol . $eol;
    $data .= "txt" . $eol;
    $data .= '--' . $mime_boundary . $eol;
    $data .= 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Converter"' . $eol . $eol;
    $data .= "pc" . $eol;
    $data .= '--' . $mime_boundary . $eol;
    $data .= 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"; filename='.$emri . $eol;
    $data .= 'Content-Type: application/pdf' . $eol;
    $data .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' . $eol . $eol;
    $data .= file_get_contents($file_src.$emri) . $eol;
    $data .= "--" . $mime_boundary . "--" . $eol . $eol; 

    $para = array('http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=' . $mime_boundary . $eol,
        'length' => 'Content-Length: '.$madhesia,
        'content' => $data
    ));

    $ctx = stream_context_create($para);

    $response = file_get_contents($destination, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH, $ctx);

    /**
     * Debug
     */         
    var_dump($response);
}
print_r($response);
?>
<form name="MainForm" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="Hidden" name="ConvertTo" value="txt" />
    <input id='albi' type="file" size="50" name="filename" />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" />
</form>
```

I hope it helps and you can find the problem. But when $response is empty you should check your connection to the other server.

Comment: no my response is not empty but my response is not what it should be. have you trie what the destination url does ?! it converts pdf to text files. i want to use that website for a few convertions that the website that im creating must do. i cant install any program on my server because i have no access to it . i want to do all in php (just php) and the above code works vary fine on WAMP (localhost) but on linux server it doesnt post the file :) i hope you understood my problem

Comment: I understood your problem. Then you should. But what is the result of your response? Perhaps the firewall blocks the connection.

Comment: if the firewall blocked the connection neither the form would post the file but if i make a form and set its action as the $destination i get correct output